# Git show doesn't work correctly outside of Git bash

Tags: git

On Windows, I am only able to get the correct behavior for `git show` in Git Bash.

```
$ git show -s --format="%ci" 319cdf6a1b94ca0358d62d93579479cfaea610cd
2014-05-07 15:58:33 -0500

$ which git
/bin/git
```

Whereas the one on my Path does not do what it is supposed to do.

```
trunk C:\dev\trunk\proj\client>git show -s --format="%ci" 319cdf6a1b94ca0358d62d93579479cfaea610cd
commit 319cdf6a1b94ca0358d62d93579479cfaea610cd
Author:
Date:   Wed May 7 15:58:33 2014 -0500

    My commit message

trunk C:\dev\trunk\proj\client>which git
git is an external : C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Is this a bug in msysgit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows the `%` characters is used for environment variables, so it was trying to expand that. To fix this, you have to use an escape.

```
git show -s --format="^%ci" 319cdf6a1b94ca0358d62d93579479cfaea610cd
```